# How to get simple text from HTML page with goquery?

Tags: html, go, goquery

I am new to Go. I am using [goquery](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery) to extract data from an HTML page. 
But the problem is the data I am looking for is not bounded by any HTML tag. It is simple text after a `<br>` tag. How can I extract it?

Edit : Here is HTML code.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <p align="justify"><b>Name</b>Priyaka</p>
        <p align="justify"><b>Surname</b>Patil</p>
        <p align="justify"><b>Adress</b><br>India,Kolhapur</p>
        <p align="justify"><b>Hobbies&nbsp;</b><br>Playing</p>
        <p align="justify"><b>Eduction</b><br>12th</p>
        <p align="justify"><b>School</b><br>New Highschool</p>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

From this I want "Priyanka" and "12th".

Comment: Maybe you just need to use `regexp` to extract your data?

Comment: Can you give an example of how that HTML looks?

Comment: <h2>When it is not to be taken (Contraindications):&nbsp;</h2> <br> Contraindicated in patients with severe liver impairment, and hypersensitivity.

Comment: I would edit your questions with that comment @Shirin

Comment: Edited. Have a look @Not_a_Golfer

Answer (score 3):

The following is what you want:

```
doc.Find(".container").Find("[align=\"justify\"]").Each(func(_ int, s *goquery.Selection) {
    prefix := s.Find("b").Text()
    result := strings.TrimPrefix(s.Text(), prefix)
    println(result)
})
```

import [strings](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/) in front of your code. If you need complete code example, check [here](https://siongui.github.io/2016/04/17/goquery-example-get-simple-text-from-html-page/).

Answer (score 0):

Try query for 
 and get its siblings

http://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.Siblings